# How do I remove default bottom padding in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code which appears fine, but in IE10 and earlier, the ul still appears with a bottom padding of about 10px. How can I remove that bottom padding in IE? All the answers I look at seem to have "margin:0; padding:0;" but I have already done that.

```
<div id="activitiesmenu">
<div>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="playgroups.html">Playgroups</a></li>
    <li><a href="outings.html">Outings</a></li>
    <li><a href="parks.html">Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="publicareas.html">Public areas</a></li>
    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

#activitiesmenu {
clear: both;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
overflow: auto;
}

#activitiesmenu div {
float: left;
width: 110px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#activitiesmenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#activitiesmenu a, #activitiesmenu li {
color: #aa4499;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Just to add, "activitiesmenu" was already styled. I have added the css above. so the "activitiesmenu div" is actually intended to style the ul as it's own div.
Also, I am a complete novice only a few weeks in from scratch so forgive any seemingly simple mistakes (like the ul opening div which I have now corrected)

Comment: Use some [CSSreset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Comment: Firstly, please specify the IE version you're testing with. Secondly, please confirm what mode the browser is running in (Standards mode, Compatibility mode, Quirks mode?). The answers to these points will make a massive difference to finding the correct answer is to your question.

Comment: What bottom padding? Please describe it in observable terms and use developer tools to determine what padding (on which element) it might be. And use valid markup (correcting it in the question too).

Answer (score 1):

First of all your opening ul tag is a closing one.

```
</ul> change to <ul>
```

Secondly your css property for #activitiesmenu div{} is setting the css properties of the child div of the parent div with id=activitiesmenu meaning:

```
#activitiesmenu div {
float: left;
width: 110px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

<div id="activitiesmenu">
<div> <-- Style applies to this div and not the top one
    <ul> <-- change
    <li><a href="mtotoplaygroups.html">Playgroups</a></li>
    <li><a href="mtotooutings.html">Outings</a></li>
    <li><a href="mtotoparks.html">Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="mtotopublicareas.html">Public areas</a></li>
    <li><a href="mtotoactivities.html">Activities</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Also try;

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have changed the ul tag. Regarding the "activitiesmenu" div, I had already styled the main div and I was intending to style the ul div seperately. The body margin and padding are already set to 0. But I still can't get rid of the bottom padding in IE..

Comment: If you are using firefox there is a nice little plugin called firebug that you can install. It shows you each elements attributes if you click on it. Or create a jsfiddle so we can try and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This At Top In Your Css File:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked! This is despite the fact that I already had the main body margin and padding set to 0. Only problem is, it has zeroed every margin and padding that I hadn't specified. But I suppose it's worth it if it fixes the problem as I can always go through and specify where needed.